# Integral of energy-momentum tensor

Tags: special-relativity

On Weinberg's *Gravitation and Cosmology* section 8 chapter 2, he introduced the energy-momentum tensor of a system of $n$ particals:

$$
T^{\alpha\beta}=\sum_np_n^{\alpha}(t)\frac{dx_n^\beta(t)}{dt}\delta^3(x-x(t))
$$

where $\delta$ is the Dirac function.

Then he argus that $T$ is not conserved, i.e.
$$
\partial_\alpha T^{\alpha\beta}\neq 0
$$

But we can introduce a purely electromagnetic term:
$$
T_{em}^{\;\;\;\alpha\beta}=F^{\alpha}_{\;\;\beta}F^{\beta\gamma}-\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\alpha\beta}F_{\gamma\delta}F^{\gamma\delta}
$$

In fact,
$$
T_{em}^{\;\;\;00}=\frac{1}{2}(E^2+B^2)
$$
and
$$
T_{em}^{\;\;\;i0}=(E\times B)_i
$$
and we can show that
$$
\tilde T^{\alpha\beta}:=T^{\alpha\beta}+T_{em}^{\;\;\;\alpha\beta}
$$
is conserved, i.e.
$$
\partial_\alpha\tilde T^{\alpha\beta}= 0
$$

Then we can calculate the total $p^{\alpha}$ by
$$
p^{\alpha}_{total}=\int d^3x\tilde T^{\alpha0}(x,t)
$$

By question is, given the value of $T_{em}^{\;\;\;00}$ and $T_{em}^{\;\;\;i0}$ above, aren't the integral infinite?

Or is this true that $E$ and $B$ are function of positions, and vanish fast enough such that the integral converges?